# Cohomology of wedge equals direct sum of cohomologies

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have seen the following fact used somewhere (for example to show that $\mathbb{RP}^3$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^3\vee\mathbb{RP}^2$):

> Let $X,Y$ be two path connected pointed spaces such that the base points each have a contractible neighborhood. Then:
>   $$H^\bullet(X\vee Y)\cong H^\bullet(X)\oplus H^\bullet(Y)$$

I have two questions:

1. In what category do we have to take the direct sum? Intuitively, I would say the category of $R$-algebras. Is it correct, or should we do it in the category of rings, or something else?
2. How can I show this? It is pretty easy to show something similar, namely that the *reduced* cohomology of the wedge of such spaces is isomorphic to the product of the reduced cohomologies *as $R$-modules* (and this is true for arbitrary wedges, not only finite ones). However, i don't know how to proceed for the statement above. Should I try to show that the universal property holds?

Comment: Strictly speaking direct sums are only defined for modules. Note that the formula is false if $X$ and $Y$ are not (path-)connected.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, I added the path-connected thing. By direct sum in categories different from the one of $R$-modules I mean the coproduct.

Comment: Surely it's not the coproduct you want here, but the product? Just thinking of the wedge of two circles over $\mathbb{Z}$, where the free product would have elements of infinite order with respect to the cup product.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Yes, you're certainly correct.

Comment: Well, now that you've restricted to path-connected spaces, you can establish the claim in degree 0 by hand and in positive degrees by reducing (hah) to reduced cohomology. No?

Comment: @ZhenLin Sure, but how can I be sure that the ring structure is what it should be?

Comment: The isomorphism of reduced cohomology of a wedge with the product of reduced cohomologies is induced by the maps $\widetilde{H}^{*}(X \vee Y) \rightarrow \widetilde{H}^{*}(X)$ and $\widetilde{H}^{*}(X \vee Y) \rightarrow \widetilde{H}^{*}(Y)$ coming from the inclusion $X, Y \hookrightarrow X \vee Y$. These are maps of algebras, so the map into the product also is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a statement about unreduced cohomology, this is incorrect (for $\bullet = 0$). The correct statement for unreduced cohomology is that

$$H^{\bullet}(X \sqcup Y) \cong H^{\bullet}(X) \times H^{\bullet}(Y)$$

where $\sqcup$ denotes the disjoint union, not the wedge sum. I write the product $\times$ on the RHS instead of the direct sum because

1. While the two have the same underlying abelian group, the correct universal property of the RHS as a ring is that it is the product, and
2. For an infinite disjoint union the answer continues to be the infinite product rather than the infinite direct sum (which lacks a multiplicative identity).

As a statement about reduced cohomology, this is fine on the level of abelian groups (and it can be proven using Mayer-Vietoris), but when taking into account the cup product you run into the annoying issue that reduced cohomology doesn't have a multiplicative identity.

One fix is to regard the cohomology of a pointed topological space $(X, \text{pt})$ as a pair consisting of a ring $H^{\bullet}(X)$ and an augmentation $H^{\bullet}(X) \to H^{\bullet}(\text{pt})$ (so reduced cohomology is the kernel of this map, also known as the augmentation ideal), and then the statement is that cohomology takes the pushout $X \vee Y$ to the corresponding pullback of the diagram $H^{\bullet}(X) \to H^{\bullet}(\text{pt}) \leftarrow H^{\bullet}(Y)$ (as an augmented ring, so keeping the induced map to $H^{\bullet}(\text{pt})$).

Answer (score 0):

1) The direct sum is a direct sum of $R$-algebras.
2) I believe that if you know the result for $R$-modules, the desired result should follow.
Indeed the induced maps in cohomology pass through the cup product:
$f^*(x \smile y) = f^*(x) \smile f^*(y)$ (ie are algebra maps).
As you must have obtained the $R$-module isomorphism via some long exact sequence, the isomorphism is certainly given by an "induced map". Therefore it should also be an algebra map.